# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts for compare/diff view?

Tags: eclipse, diff, shortcut

When I am comparing two files in Eclipse (using, for example, "Compare With" --> "Local History"), what keyboard shortcuts are available?

I would like to be able to go to the next/previous diff and copy the selected diff left without having to click the tiny little buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can define whatever you want to be a short cut for this. Preferences->General->Editors->Keys.
EDIT:
For some reason I don't see that option appears there. O_o

Comment: Ah, yup – the trick is that you've got to check "Include unbound commands."  Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

To complete [Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104014/artem-barger)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907232/6309), after `Preferences->General->Editors->Keys`, search for:

- Select next change
- Select previous change
- Copy from Left to Right
- Copy from Right to Left

All those keys in the "`Compare`" section have no shortcut assign by default, so you can add the ones of your choice.

[image: http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/comparebefore.png]

Comment: See my comment on Artem's answer regarding including unbound commands.  Anyway, I hope you're not offended if I give him the "answer" – he was first, and could probably use the rep ;)

Comment: @David: no problem, and certainly no "offense" taken ;) I was merely completing his answer.

Comment: You can also use the Next/Previous commands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177460/is-there-a-key-binding-for-next-difference-and-previous-difference-in-eclipse-co

Comment: Was there any change in Eclipse 4.2? All my bindings for next/prev difference/change which were working fine in 3.7 (Indigo) stopped working now. I have `When` set to `Comparing in an Editor` and no conflicts.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Not sure (I don't have access to 4.2 just now). +1 to your answer though.

Comment: Key bindings in `Text Compare` window do not work in Eclipse 4.2 - see bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376491 They keep breaking things in Eclipse all the time. It's high time to switch to competition.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, I'm on 4.3.1 and they *do* work for me, only when using letters in the hotkey; it's specifically arrows (non-letters?) that do not work.  (I have an edit pending on Jeremy's answer, since he specifically suggests using arrows.)

Answer (score 15):

Set your own keys as instructed by @Artem and @VonC.
In Eclipse Galileo, however, the path is `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`.

For each command you wish to set:

1. Click on the Command Name 
   *TIP: Sort by "Category" to group all "Compare" commands.*
2. Click on the "Binding" textbox 
   Then, select the keys you wish to use, Eclipse will record them for you.
   *TIP: You can enter a sequence of keys in addition to key combination(s).*
3. Set "When" drop down box to "Comparing in an Editor."
   *TIP: This setting will limit your hot key(s) to only be activate in the chosen context.*

---

Intuitive Hot Key settings: (my recommendations, not from a standard)

- Copy All from Left to Right <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Right</kbd>
- Copy All from Right to Left <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Right</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Left</kbd>
- Copy from Left to Right  <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd>
- Copy from Right  to Left <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd>
- Select next change <kbd>Ctrl+Down</kbd>
- Select previous change <kbd>Ctrl+Up</kbd>

Comment: You don't necessarily need to bind "Select next/previous change" to a custom hotkey, you can jump to the next/previous diff by pressing Ctrl+. and Ctrl+,  ...

Actually, this hotkeys jump to the next/previous annotations in the current editor, so it works also for error-markers and warnings in the standard Java-editor, but since the diff-editor only shows diffs, it works as intended here.

Comment: On a sidenote: is there a hotkey available to switch the cursor the corresponding line of the other diff-side when the diff-editor is active?

Comment: @arne.jans, "Select next change" will move between multiple changes in a line, so it is also useful to have that bound. Strangely previous does not work the same way.

Comment: @arne.jans `Ctrl+.` and `Ctrl+,` are standard key bindings for selecting next/previous difference not for selecting next/previous change. See my answer for more details.

Comment: `Ctrl+Down` and `Ctrl+Up` activate the scrolling (for me) and cannot be overridden with "Select [previous|next] change" without further adjustments.

Comment: @Bowi They move the cursor for me, as do Ctrl+Left Shift+Ctrl+Left (and +Right), even when bound. We need different keys.

Answer (score 9):

With eclipse, when you are in a window and you have a button to do a action but this button doesn't have a tooltip to show you his shortcut, go to **`Navigate`** menu.
The most of time, shortcuts are shown there.

[image]

Comment: So based on these I've mapped `Ctrl+Shift+.` to 'Copy from left to right' and `Ctrl+Shift+,` to 'Copy from right to left' for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

There is a catch. There are no `Next Difference` and `Previous Difference` entries in the key bindings editor. These two buttons in a compare window are bind to `Next` and `Previous` entries in the key bindings editor. See [Is there a key binding for Next Difference and Previous Difference in Eclipse Compare Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10177460/95735)

I raised a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401129 which can be voted on.