# Is there a key binding for Next Difference and Previous Difference in Eclipse Compare Editor?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In compare editor there are [buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773648/)

- Next Difference
- Previous Difference
- Next Change
- Previous Change

I'd like to assign key bindings for *Next Difference* and *Previous Difference* buttons. However in preferences I see only *Select Next Change* and *Select Previous Change* commands (both in category *Compare*). How can I assign key bindings to buttons referring to differences?

My Eclipse:
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are default shortcuts for these:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (`next`) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (`previous`)

Comment: Now, when you said this I recall I had seen these shortcuts in the past but apparently forgot them. It's strange a) these default shortcuts are not shown on tooltips and b) they are not exposed in case someone wanted to change them...

Comment: Bonus question: Can I change these default key bindings?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys. Search for 'next' and 'previous' to find entries with the mentioned shortcuts (just called 'Next' and 'Previous'). There you should be able to change the binding

Comment: They are called just *Next* and *Previous* indeed. I was looking for *change* earlier. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working in Eclipse Mars, it's toggling files, not differences within the file.

Answer (score 3):

**Next Difference, Previous Difference**:

- No key mapping (still in Eclipse Neon ) :(

**Next Change, Previous Change:**

- Set "When" to "Comparing in an Editor" worked for me.

[image]

Comment: "Comparing in an Editor" is the one I have been searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Mars, it is still the same process as moeTi explained. I am adding some details. To set custom keyboard shortcuts, go to:

- Open Window->Preferences
- General->Keys

Here's a list of the commands you would want and the associated mapping:

- **Previous Difference** (Select the previous difference in the comparison editor)

  - Command '**Previous**' in category '**Navigate**'
- **Next Difference**  (Select the next difference in the comparison editor)

  - The command '**Next**' in category '**Navigate**'
- **Copy Current Change from Right to Left** (replace your code with theirs)

  - The command '**Copy from Right to Left**' in category '**Compare**'
- **Copy Current Change from Left to Right** (generally not an option)

  - The command '**Copy from Left to Right**' in category '**Compare**'

Comment: It's not working. "Next" just jumps to the next file, not the next difference in the file :(

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? Eclipse Java EE Mars? Or something else?